# jQuery sending ajax request to homepage.. if id exists add class to current page

Tags: jquery, ajax, if-statement, request

I'm not sure if this is correct way of doing things but hopefully someone will understand.  I simply need to send a request to the homepage and check to see if an ID exists, if it exists I need to add a class to an ID on the Current page (or do other jQuery for that matter).  I think there is something wrong with my URL because it works fine when im actually ON the homepage.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$.ajax({
  url: "/",
  context: document.body, 
  success: function(){
       if ($('#welcome').length == 1 )
            {    
                    $('#login').addClass("done");        
             }   
  }
});
});
```

Comment: What are you even doing on the server that you need to make an AJAX call here?

Comment: I cant change anything on the server.  When you are logged in it automatically adds a welcome text with id 'welcome' to the homepage only.  I basically am checking to see when logged in but on every page.

Comment: Yeah but...your not returning any data from the AJAX call, so what are you checking?

Comment: It should be noted that this can be a huge security problem and the hidden content could easily be viewed without permission.

Comment: nono, This is a Volusion site.  There is no way of telling if someone is logged in or not unless your on the homepage, it will say "Welcome so and soo" if you are logged in.  I want to check to see if that ID exists, if it exists I want to add a class somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your checking the current page when you do this call,

```
 if ($('#welcome').length == 1 )
```

so you would only get a true answer if the current page is the home page. What your looking to do is actually check the data that is returned from the ajax call. To do that, your success handler much accept the data that is being passed to it.

```
  success: function(data){
       if ($(data).find('#welcome').length >= 1) {    
           $('#login').addClass("done");        
       }   
  }
```

Comment: Couldnt get this one working for me, whether the id 'welcome' existed on the homepage or not.

Comment: Can you verify that the success function is getting the page contents back the data parameter? You might need to add a dataType: 'html' to your ajax call.

Comment: F'ing genius, that makes sense.  First time I've ever entered any ajax info before thanks for clarifying this makes sense why it wasn't working.  I had to add the dataType is was trying to search which was html.

Answer (score 1):

Since the AJAX request will return what the page echoes as data, you can try just searching that data for the id:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/",
  context: document.body, 
  success: function(data){
       if (data.indexOf('id="welcome"') >= 0) {    
           $('#login').addClass("done");        
       }   
  }
});
```

However, like @Paramount said, this isn't a good way to check if someone is logged in.

Comment: This is adding the class "done" whether id "welcome" exists on the homepage or not, I need it to add "done" when id "welcome" exists on the homepage.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$.ajax({
 url: "/",
context: document.body, 
success: function(){
   if ($(this).find('#welcome').length > 0)
        {    
                $('#login').addClass("done");        
         }   
}
});    
});
```

Or:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$.ajax({
 url: "/",
context: document.body, 
success: function(){
   if ($(this).attr('id') == 'welcome')
        {    
                $('#login').addClass("done");        
         }   
}
});    
});
```

Or (using PHP as an example):

```
    <?php
    if (isset($loggedin)) {
    ?>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#login').addClass("done");
    });
</script>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: This only works on the homepage when logged in.  Does not work on other pages if logged in.

Comment: Then it's much easier than this. If you are checking to see if the person in logged in every time the page is loaded, check the login variable in whatever language you are using and simply add the class via a one line jquery call.

Comment: See the PHP example I put in above. You shouldn't need an ajax call if you are checking the log in status on each page. I have done something very similar with PHP, ColdFusion, and ASP.NET. Volusion should have a way of checking to see if someone is logged in. If it only checks on the homepage, that doesn't make sense. But, check with Volusion. If you pay for it, there should be some type of support service that can point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

The other thing you could do is create a namespaced 'global' variable (global to your code) that saves the logged in state, e.g

```
var myjQ {
    ...
    loggedIn : false;
    ...
}

if myjQ.loggedIn {
    // do stuff
} else {
   // do other stuff
}
```

Comment: I think I understand what your saying, however I am using Volusion and it does not know what the global variable is for log ins.  If this can be achieved would I have to make some sort of modifications to the server because I doubt it reads 'loggedIn: false'  unless you know something I dont?

Comment: Todd - Your code doesn't need to know the Volusion login variable. Assuming that you have your javascript(jQuery) code on all the pages, create a variable that retains the user's logged in state. Set the variable when the user logs in, get the variable on your other pages.